# Terraform Run Before Destroy

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

There is a Terraform kubernetes_job which enables a ssh key on EKS nodes. The same job can remove the ssh key.

If the module which runs the job is disabled before the ssh key is disabled - the ssh key remains enabled on the EKS nodes and the module is destroyed. This create an insecure environment.

One solution tried out was using a null_resource with a provisioner set to when = destroy, rerun the job so as to disable the ssh key. However this didn't work.

```
resource "null_resource" "run_before_destroy" {

  triggers = {
    uuid  = kubernetes_job.ssh_toggle_job.id
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when = destroy
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    command = "TF_WORKSPACE=dev terraform apply -target module.components.module.ssh_toggle[0].kubernetes_job.ssh_toggle_job -lock=false -auto-approve"
  }
}
```

Essentially, when the module is set to destroy via either an apply or via destroy, the job should run and disable the ssh key first, and then allow the destroy process to finish out destroying the module.

Is this possible or am I barking up the wrong solution tree? :~)

## Didn't work

As in Terraform went into an infinite loop, never exiting.

## Job destruction

Yes when the module is disabled, to run the job so as to disable the ssh key, then allow destroy to continue as usual by removing the module.

Comment: "didn't work" is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: Not sure I understand. So you want to run a job on a cluster which is effectively getting destroyed? In other words, the EKS destruction starts and that is the moment when you want to run the K8s job?